# Woocommerce PayPal sandbox not getting disabled

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I am not able to disable PayPal sandbox.

On the settings I am un-checking the sandbox & saving. But these settings are not getting applied. After checkout on the website its taking the user to `sandbox.paypal.com` and the payment is not processed. Actually I never enabled sandbox on my website.

Comment: You need to provide more information such as your settings.

Comment: Checkout Settings on Woocommerce for PayPal. PayPal standard is enabled, sandbox disabled, debug log enabled. Thats it